# How to change label value using jQuery, without selecting by class or ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

This is my first question. On My Form, I want change text "Color" to "Choose Color".

```
<label for="ProductSelect-option-0">Color</label>
```

output will be

```
<label for="ProductSelect-option-0">Choose Color</label>
```

Without adding class or ID. How is it possible to do with jQuery?

Comment: We need more of your HTML in order to see how to traverse the DOM to find the element. Also note that it would be *far* better to actually update the HTML source instead of 'patching' it with JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select by element type with a certain prop

```js
$('label[for="ProductSelect-option-0"]').text('Choose Color');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ProductSelect-option-0">Color</label>
```

Comment: @LindaCapellini You tagged your question jQuery, but I suspect you didn't include it in your source. The jsFiddle is definitive proof this code works

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag, here's a css approach

```
label[for="ProductSelect-option-0"]::before {
   content: "Choose ";
   display: inline-block;
}
```